# How can I share a .m4a file to whatsapp with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, share, whatsapp

I want to share a `.m4a` file to whatsapp but I did not understand how can I do that?

Here is my code.

```
var controller = UIDocumentInteractionController()

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"whatsapp://app")!) {

    var savePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType:"m4a")

    controller          = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath:savePath!)!)
    controller.UTI      = "net.whatsapp.audio"
    controller.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)

}
else {
    println("error")
}
```

Comment: did you get the the `println("error"`) ?

Comment: Why dont you share with UIActivityViewController?

Comment: because UIActivity doesnt show whatsup in list. if i share text uiactivty works fine... Also i solved my problem.

Comment: var controller = UIDocumentInteractionController()       //GLOBALLLLLL                 controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: selectedAudioUrl!)
 
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"whatsapp://app")!) {
            
            controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: selectedAudioUrl!)
            controller.UTI = "net.whatsapp.audio"
            controller.delegate=self
            controller.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
            
        }

Comment: can is ask u a question. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772969/hear-recording-voice-and-background-track-at-the-same-time-with-ios-swift  @SaqibOmer

Comment: Yes you can. @davudi

Comment: I am able to record entire audio stream including background track  when headphone plugged into device, i want to hear my voice and background track same time from headphone. But i hear only background track. How can i do that? @SaqibOmer

Comment: @SaqibOmer why dont you answer it?

Comment: I will post answer once I get free.

Comment: @SaqibOmer i will wait..